# Convert a date to integer within parameter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Right now I have a Stored procedure which takes a date as an `integer` (140213) but within `SSRS` I need to convert the date selected within the `date parameter` to the `integer` mentioned before.

Right now I am trying to achieve this by having 2 parameters (date and convert), one that lets you select a date, and the 2nd trying to convert the date to an int. Within the 2nd parameter in the Default value I have:

```
=FormatNumber(Format(Parameters!date.Value, "yyMMdd"),0)
```

The 2nd parameter is set to internal and the data type set to integer.

When I try to run this report I get the error

```
The property 'DefaultValue' of report paramater 'convert' doesn't have the expected type.
```

Any idea on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The optimal solution is to modify the stored procedure to accept a date/datetime parameter.**
This prevents unnecessary conversion and confusing representation of dates with single digit years as an integer type (e.g. `2009-01-01` -> `90101`)

Assuming you have no control over the stored procedure definition, you can still achieve what you want using the steps below. These assume existence of two parameters:

- *Date* (user input from SSRS date control)
- *ConvertedDate* (integer representing converted *Date* value)

### Steps

1. Set the `ConvertedDate` **Data Type** to *Integer* and **parameter visibility** to *Internal*
   [image: Internal parameter visibility]
2. Set the `ConvertedDate` **default value** to *Specify Values* using expression:

   ```
   =CInt(Format(Parameters!Date.Value, "yyMMdd"))
   ```

   [image: Parameter default value expression]
3. `ConvertedDate` parameter value can now be passed to stored procedure. Sample report output with `Date` selection and `ConvertedDate` value:

   [image: Sample report]