# Convert a date to an integer in YYYYMMDD format in SSRS

Tags: date, reporting-services, integer, numeric

What is the equivalent expression in SSRS of the following conversion of a date (@Date) in T-SQL?

```
CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(CHAR,@Date,112))
```

I need the date parameter value to be converted to an integer in YYYYMMDD format.

Comment: seems this would do it too ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782194/convert-a-date-to-integer-within-parameter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have a date parameter called `YourDate`.

You could use the following expression:

```
=Cint(Format(Parameters!YourDate.Value, "yyyyMMdd"))
```

---

Explanation:

Step 1: Format the date to the `yyyyMMdd` format:

```
Format(Parameters!YourDate.Value, "yyyyMMdd")
```

Step 2: Cast the result as an int:

```
Cint(<FormattedDate>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dry coding here, but try...

```
=Fields!MyDateColumn.Value.Year * 10000 + Fields!MyDateColumn.Value.Month * 100 + Fields!MyDateColumn.Value.Date
```

Comment: Thanks, JC.  I started down a similar path:
=YEAR(Parameters!MyDate.Value)*10000 + MONTH(Parameters!MyDate.Value)*100 + DAY(Parameters!MyDate.Value)

But, the alternate method suggested by Sébastien Sevrin works well too and is a little shorter:
=Cint(Format(Parameters!MyDate.Value, "yyyyMMdd"))

Answer (score 0):

Try the following expression :-

```
=format(cdate(Parameters!Date.Value),"yyyyMMdd")
```