# SSRS Converting int to date and handling #Error

Tags: reporting-services

I'm a bit of an SSRS newbie and I'm having some trouble converting an Int to a Date in SSRS. The `publication_date.Value` is fed from a proprietary database as an Int type (so we unfortunately have no control over that) in the format 20160519.

The following works splendidly when there is a value present:

```
=CDate(Left(Fields!publication_date.Value, 4) + "-" + Mid(Fields!publication_date.Value, 5, 2) + "-" + Right(Fields!publication_date.Value, 2))
```

However, when there is a null it returns an #Error, which I'd like to suppress. I've tried using an IIf statement but without success.

```
=Iif(Fields!publication_date.Value is nothing,"", CDate(Left(Fields!publication_date.Value, 4) + "-" + Mid(Fields!publication_date.Value, 5, 2) + "-" + Right(Fields!publication_date.Value, 2)))
```

I've been digging around for other solutions but yet to find anything that works. Please help!

**Edited -** thanks for the duplicate article suggestion, however I need to convert an Int to a Date and handle the errors, not a Date to an Int.

Comment: Could you try this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27409605/2451726)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a date to an integer in YYYYMMDD format in SSRS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31253180/convert-a-date-to-an-integer-in-yyyymmdd-format-in-ssrs)

Comment: Thanks @Arulkumar - that works a treat :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue,

As per your example, do one thing.

Keep you expression same like below,

```
=CDate(Left(Fields!publication_date.Value, 4) + "-" + Mid(Fields!publication_date.Value, 5, 2) + "-" + Right(Fields!publication_date.Value, 2))
```

Now, tricky part would be, in textbox visibility use below expression.

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!publication_date.Value),True,False)
```

It will definitely work. Let me know if you face any issue. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! Works great.